# Pip is not installed with python 3.7.3 even i did selected it on install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I installed python to my new computer (Windows 7). I needed to use pip to install packages but I couldn't find it in the folder where it was supposed to be located.

I have tried to bootstrap it

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

and get-pip.py didn't work either (Got a bunch of errors)

I have looked for the folder it should be in to make sure I was looking in the right place

```py
import os
import sys
print (os.path.dirname(sys.executable) + '\Scripts\\')
```

which gives
'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\'
as an output (Folder where I was looking in the first place). That folder is empty. I have 'show hidden files, folders and drives' on, I have searched for it from my entire computer, re-installed python and tried older (and 3.7.4 since it was released the time i noticed that pip was missing) versions, i have even added that empty folder to PATH and called for pip to make sure that it isn't just hidden from me. I have ran a repair and modify on installer too. Am I just missing some obvious step or is something wrong elsewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Double-Click again on your python3.7 Windows x86 executable installer (i.e: setup.exe file). Then follow this pattern click on Modify > pip > add python to environment variable

[image: image1]

[image: image1]
[image: image3]

Finally click on install and its done . * Note I am using python3.6.7 but the steps are same for python3.7.3

Comment: The OP said they did select installing `pip`.

Comment: This did not work for me. The pip option is checked, but pip is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having trouble installing pip just do the following things.

1. Install Python 3x normally.
2. Go to properties of my computer -> Advance system settings -> new -> give vairable name as Path and variable value as the location of Python scripts and save it in my case it is.

   > C:\Users\Atharva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts
3. Restart your computer and open cmd.
4. now you can use pip commands.
5. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install –upgrade pip' command.

Thats all

Comment: Try installing it from scratch again

Comment: The Scripts folder is absolutely empty in my fresh installation of Python 3.10 with pip option checked.

Answer (score -2):

Type the following command in a CMD window:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

This will download and install pip as a package. This code worked for me.

Comment: This is the first thing the asker tried as described in their question. They specifically say it didn't work for them.